# HTML-KickStart Tool Tip Error

Tags: html, apache, tooltip, html5-kickstart

So I have spent more than an hour trying to figure this out.

I am trying to use a ToolTip from html5-kickstart and it doesn't seem to work when I use it, but the kickstart's kitchen sink works fine. I even copied all of their code into my web server and it didn't work?

I copied their headers and it didn't work, copied their code and it didn't work.

I am using Apache 2 pretty much out of the box. everything else html5 seems to work fine, but kickstart's tool tip.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Please Set name in fuction!</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxdesk/css/mainpage.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxdesk/css/kickstart.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxdesk/css/tiptip.css" />
        <script src="http://192.168.77.74/xxxxdesk/js/mainpage.js" ></script>
        <script src="http://192.168.77.74/xxxxdesk/js/kickstart.js" ></script>
        <script src="http://192.168.77.74/xxxxdesk/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="http://192.168.77.74/xxxxdesk/js/helium.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="title" class="col_8 left">
            <span>xxxxdesk<span>
        </div>

        <div id="login" class="col_4 right">

            <!-- Click Action -->
            <button class="tooltip" data-content="#usermenu" data-action="click">
                <i class="icon-user"></i> UserName <i class="icon-sort-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="tooltip-content" id="usermenu"><h5>Menu</h5>
                <button class="button meduim red pill" href="index.php/auth/logout">Logout</button>
            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>


</nav>

<div class="background">    
    <header>
        A header .........
    </header>

    <main>
        Content ...........
    </main>
</div>

<footer>
    A Footer ..............
</footer>
```

Please note that all this code is generated by my PHP code. So it is a dynamic site, but this is all that matters concerning HTML5 Kickstart.

Comment: Just to clarify this is the kickstart i am using because there is two that do the same thing but go by different names.

http://www.99lime.com/elements/#tooltip-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out.

The kitchen sink displays an older version of the package, and it uses an older version of jQuery.

My 1st mistake was that I had the old version of jQuery.

My 2nd mistake was that I was calling jQuery after I called kickstart.js. jQuery needs to come first.

I hope this help others down the road.